# Unable to update from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates

I'm trying to update from 12.04 to 13.04 but I firstly need to go thorugh 12.10, using Update Manager.
This is the error I get.
E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)

Please don't mark this as "duplicate", I have searched and found troubles like this but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below command on a terminal (to open, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) & type below command. And then run the update manager again

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

P.S.: Please edit your question and post the output, if you come across any errors.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it and I'm not running 13.04 :)

Comment: Glad it fixed. :)